# How to move script in a view to a separate js file in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using:
Ruby version: 2.2 Rails version: 4.2

I am attempting to make use of the asset pipeline in terms of JavaScript, I understand and have working stylesheets, but I cannot separate my js from my view.

Example:

```
// view.html.erb 
<body> 
  <div id="slider"></div> 
</body> 


// assets/javascript/slider.js
$( "#slider" ).slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 10000,
  value: 0,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#SolarAmount" ).val(ui.value + " sq. ft.");
  }
});
```

But the slider is nowhere to be found. However, If I include the function inside the view.html.erb it works as expected. If anyone can offer some advice about how the pipeline works with javascript I would appreciate the help!

Comment: It appears that **no** .js files that I include in the assets/javascipt/ directory are being utilized, not just this one. Do I need to add them to be precompiled or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should nearly always enclose that type of code in the [jQuery ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function. If the javascript is at the top of the document, it will execute before the div exists.

The jQuery ready function executes code when the DOM is fully loaded. 99% of the time, this is what you'll want.

For example, you need to do this:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 10000,
    value: 0,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#SolarAmount" ).val(ui.value + " sq. ft.");
    }
  });
});
```

Make sure you're including the application javascript file in your template, as Mario suggests. Assuming you're using the `jquery-rails` gem, your application.js should look something like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

As in, you need to make sure you include jQuery before all the other js files in the directory (`require_tree .`).

Comment: Oh okay, that explains why the slider only appears if I put the script at the bottom of the view. If I move the above to its own slider.js will I be able to reference it with the div like my example above?

Comment: Absolutely. If it still doesn't work, you need to make sure you're including the javascript files in your template properly (Mario's answer covers this), and jQuery needs to be included first. Also, check your console for errors.

Comment: yes my application.html.erb is as Mario said and my application.js file looks like above. If I use the js you gave me as it is it should work fine right? Like I do not need anything else format wise?

Comment: Where is the slider library located? Perhaps your `slider.js` file is being being included before your slider library is loaded. You might need to manually require your slider library before `require_tree`. As I mentioned, you need to check your console (as in web browser console) for errors.

Comment: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"):  ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"):  So I think you are right, I think it's an issue with loading the library, let me try a few things.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're importing your `application.js` file in your `app/views/layout/application.html.erb` file.

It should have this line: `<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`

Also make sure your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file is properly set up (most likely is)

Comment: The above line is in my application.html.er and I followed the other comments advice about the .ready() function but still no luck! It is as if it's not using any of the js files in the asset folder.

Comment: just to make certain, since you wrote the path on your main question... are you saving the javascript files to a folder named app/assets/javascripts, or javascript? It should be plural

Comment: the full path of the js is app/assets/javascripts/silder.js

Comment: could you try creating another file, say test.js, and just adding an alert to it? `$( function() { alert("if you see this, the pipeline works"); } );` and restarting the server?

Comment: Yes! That means the pipeline is at least working lol could it be the way I referenced the slider in the view? I just made a div for it per API instructions.

Comment: Where is the slider library you're using coming from? jquery-ui? The way you reference the object seems fine. Is there something else in the view? A javascript src tag maybe? Also did you change your function to reflect Christian's answer? (Wrapping it in a jquery ready function?)

Answer (score 0):

If you're fighting with turbolinks, you may need to put your js code inside a turbolinks ready function.

Something like this:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function(){
  $( "#slider" ).slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 10000,
    value: 0,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#SolarAmount" ).val(ui.value + " sq. ft.");
    }
  });
});
```

You'll know if you're fighting with turbolinks when you see your js working when you refresh the page but not when you navigate from another page in your app.